# R: Automatically Producing Histograms

Tags: r, loops, ggplot2, data-visualization, histogram

I am using the R programming language. I created the following data set for this example:

```
var_1 <- rnorm(1000,10,10)
var_2 <- rnorm(1000, 5, 5)
var_3 <- rnorm(1000, 6,18)

favorite_food <- c("pizza","ice cream", "sushi", "carrots", "onions", "broccoli", "spinach", "artichoke", "lima beans", "asparagus", "eggplant", "lettuce", "cucumbers")
favorite_food <-  sample(favorite_food, 1000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.5, 0.45, 0.04, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001))


response <- c("a","b")
response <- sample(response, 1000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.3, 0.7))


data = data.frame( var_1, var_2, var_3, favorite_food, response)

data$favorite_food = as.factor(data$favorite_food)
data$response = as.factor(data$response)
```

From here, I want to make histograms for the two categorical variables in this data set and put them on the same page:

```
#make histograms and put them on the same page (note: I don't know why the "par(mfrow = c(1,2))" statement is not working)
par(mfrow = c(1,2))

histogram(data$response, main = "response"))

histogram(data$favorite_food, main = "favorite food"))
```

[image]

My question : Is it possibly to automatically produce histograms for all categorical variables (without manually writing the "histogram()" statement for each variable) in a given data set and print them on the same page? Is it better to the use the "ggplot2" library instead for this problem ?

I can manually write the "histogram()" statement for each individual categorical variables in the data set, but I was looking for a quicker way to do this. Is it possible to do this with a "for loop"?

Thanks

Comment: NB this code isn't quite reproducible as you haven't said which package you are using to call `histogram` and there appear to be some superfluous brackets at the end of  those calls

Comment: [As a subsequent question suggests, I think the OP was using `hist` but wrote `histogram` here.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a base R alternative using `barplot` in `for` loop :

```
cols <- names(data)[sapply(data, is.factor)]


#This would need some manual adjustment if number of columns increase
par(mfrow = c(1,length(cols))) 

for(i in cols) {
  barplot(table(data[[i]]), main = i)
}
```

[image]

Comment: is there a way to avoid this error - Error in plot.new() : figure margins are too large?

Comment: Have you tried suggestions from this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23050928/error-in-plot-new-figure-margins-too-large-scatter-plot

Answer (score 4):

A `ggplot2`/`tidyverse` solution is to lengthen each column into data and then use faceting to plot them all in the same page:

(with edit to plot only factor variables)

```
factor_vars <- sapply(data, is.factor)

varnames <- names(data)

deselect_not_factors <- varnames[!factor_vars]

library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

data_long <- data %>%
  pivot_longer(
    cols = -deselect_not_factors,
    names_to = "category",
    values_to = "value"
  )

ggplot(data_long) +
  geom_bar(
    aes(x = value)
  ) +
  facet_wrap(~category, scales = "free")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! But suppose the variables all have different names - is there a way to only select categorical variables (i.e. factor)?

Comment: I've edited to do this by working out which cols are factors then excluding them in the `cols` argument to `pivot_longer`

Comment: Thank you so much! Just a question: is it possible to replace the "pivot_longer" startement using functions from the "dplyr" and "reahape2" library? Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: You might be able to get the same result as `pivot_longer` using some stuffing around with `melt` and `cast` from `reshape2` but there's no real reason to still be using that package. `tidyverse` (including `dplyr` and `tidyr`) are the modern and more user friendly evolution from `reshape2`. Message: just install `tidyr`

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative, you can capitalize on the fantastic [DataExplorer package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DataExplorer/vignettes/dataexplorer-intro.html).

Note that histograms are for continuous variables and hence, you wanted to create bar plots for your categorical variables. This can be done as follows:

```
if(require(DataExplorer)==FALSE) install.packages("DataExplorer"); library(DataExplorer)
DataExplorer::plot_histogram(data) # plots histograms for continuous variables
DataExplorer::plot_bar(data) # bar plots for categorical variables
```

Please refer to the [package manual](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DataExplorer/DataExplorer.pdf) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a try using `cowplot` & `ggplot2`

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(foreach)
library(cowplot)

list_variables <- c("response", "favorite_food")
all_plot <- foreach(current_var = c(list_variables)) %do% {
  # need to do this to avoid ggplot reference to same summary data afterward.
  data_summary_name <- paste0(current_var, "_summary")
  eval(substitute(
    {
      graph_data <- data %>%
        group_by(!!sym(current_var)) %>%
        summarize(count = n(), .groups = "drop") %>%
        mutate(share = count / sum(count))
      plot <- ggplot(graph_data) +
        geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = !!sym(current_var), y = share), width = 1,
          fill = "#00FFFF", color = "#000000", stat = "identity") +
        scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
        ggtitle(current_var) + ylab("Perecent of Total") +
        theme_bw()
    }, list(graph_data = as.name(data_summary_name))
  )) 
  return(plot)
}

plot_grid(plotlist = all_plot, ncol = 2)
```

[image]

*Note: For reference about why I use `eval` & `substitue` you can reference to this question on [ggplot2 generate same plot for different variables in a for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67085962/ggplot2-generate-same-plot-for-different-variables-in-a-for-loop/67101787#67101787)*

Using `facet_wrap` as approach similar to **QuishSwash** with data calculated in share instead

```r
list_variables <- c("response", "favorite_food")
# Calculate share for choosen variables defined in list_variables 
# You can adjust by having some variables selection based on some condition
summary_df <- bind_rows(foreach(current_var = c(list_variables)) %do% {
  data %>%
    group_by(variable = !!sym(current_var)) %>%
    summarize(count = n(), .groups = "drop") %>%
    mutate(share = count / sum(count),
      variable_name = current_var)
})

ggplot(summary_df) +
  geom_bar(
    aes(x = variable, y = share),
    fill = "#00FFFF", color = "#000000", stat = "identity") +
  facet_wrap(~variable_name, scales = "free") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-04-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: thank you! Is there a way to replace the list_variables object, and automatically put all the variable names into list_variables, without individually writing them?

Comment: @stats555 there are many ways to do that, and already stated in others answers. It really depend on your dataset. In this case if just factor then `cols <- names(data)[sapply(data, is.factor)]` from @RonakShah answer is concise and beautiful